# Not able to iterate List using Iterator, but working fine when using for each

Tags: java, spring, collections, iterator

Populating the Question Bean with Answer Bean from applicationContext.xml
and error is thrown when am iterating List of Answer  using Iterator, but working fine with For Each loop.

```
 {        


<bean id="answer1" class="com.core.spring.Answer">  
<property name="id" value="1"></property>  
<property name="answerText" value="Java is a programming language"></property>  
<property name="by" value="Ravi Malik"></property>  
</bean>  
<bean id="answer2" class="com.core.spring.Answer">  
<property name="id" value="2"></property>  
<property name="answerText" value="Java is a platform"></property>  
<property name="by" value="Sachin"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="answer3" class="com.core.spring.Answer">  
<property name="id" value="3"></property>  
<property name="answerText" value="Java is a platform"></property>  
<property name="by" value="Sachin"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="question" class="com.core.spring.Question">
<property name="id" value="1"></property>
<property name="questionText" value="What is Java?"></property>
<property name="answers">
<list>
<ref bean="answer1"/>
<ref bean="answer2"/>
<ref bean="answer3"/>

</list>
</property>
</bean>

}
```

This is the Bean Class of Question.

```
{
  package com.core.spring;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Question {

        private int id;
        String questionText;
        List<Answer> answers=new ArrayList<Answer>();


        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getQuestionText() {
            return questionText;
        }
        public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
            this.questionText = questionText;
        }
        public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
            return answers;
        }
        public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
            this.answers = answers;
        }

        public void displayInfo(){

            System.out.println("Question: "+id);
            System.out.println(questionText);
            System.out.println("Answers");

            for(Answer ans:answers){
                System.out.print(ans.getId());
                System.out.println(": "+ans.getAnswerText());
            }

            for (Iterator<Answer> ans = answers.iterator(); ans.hasNext();){
                System.out.print(ans.next().getId());
                System.out.println(": "+ans.next().getAnswerText());

            }
            /*Iterator<Answer> ans=answers.iterator();
            while(ans.hasNext()){
                System.out.print(ans.next().getId());
                System.out.println(": "+ans.next().getAnswerText());
            }*/
        }

    }**

}
```

Comment: Why would you say there is an error and not post the error?

Comment: You're calling `next()` **twice** inside the loop...

Comment: Yes Realised it now, thanx for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That loop should be like this

```
 for (Iterator<Answer> ans = answers.iterator(); ans.hasNext();){
                Answer ans = ans.next();
                System.out.print(ans.getId());
                System.out.println(": "+ans.getAnswerText());

            }
```

You are calling `next()`  method in each `System.out.println()`

```
 for (Iterator<Answer> ans = answers.iterator(); ans.hasNext();){
                System.out.print(ans.next().getId());  //moving one element
                System.out.println(": "+ans.next().getAnswerText());  //moving one element

            }
```

Which obviously leads to odd results while printing them.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of the `Iterator` is wrong - `next()` moves the iterator to the next position, and you're calling it **twice** from the `while` loop's body, and only cheking `hasNext()` once.

You should only call `next()` once, extract its value to a local variable and use it how many times you need:

```
Iterator<Answer> ans = answers.iterator();
while(ans.hasNext()) {
    Answer answer = ans.next();
    System.out.print(answer.getId());
    System.out.println(": " + answer.getAnswerText());
}
```